# Custom currency formatting in Power BI

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

How can I show the sales amount i.e., 1,444,355 to "$ 1.4 M" format in power BI chart and tables, I am able to do it like this format $1.4M without any space.

I am trying different combination of custom formatting string but still not able to get it done
Can anyone help me to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression:

```
Sales Amount = Format(1444355 / 1e6, "$ #.0 M")
```

[image]

Comment: Was this answer working for you?